# How is the div style from gmail-sent messages (gmail_quote) formatted in other mail clients?

Tags: css, gmail

I'm trying to format quoting of emails similar to gmail. I noticed that gmail formats the original message with a div that has a style class of gmail_quote. How do other mail clients pick up this style? Is it up to each of them to implement that on their own and display it properly? If so, is there a commonly understood (published) reference to what that style is?

```
<div class="gmail_quote">
```

`

Dear YALDA 

 

Please see emails and link below....we hope the deadline has not passed.

 

YALDA team

 

------------------------------------------------

Would it be appropriate to share the link below with the YALDA e-mail lists? A subject line like **"Economist Debates: Africa and China"- Weigh In on the Debate!** would be fine, but we can also get creative if you want with it! Pretty sure today is the last to provide commentary, so I hope we can send it out!  

Thanks,
Martha_________________________
Martha Tesfalul
Johns Hopkins School of Medicine, MS1
tesfalul@jhmi.edu
(713) 576 9306 



---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: Juma, Calestous <calestous_juma@harvard.edu>
Date: Sat, Feb 20, 2010 at 4:08 AM
Subject: 
To: "martha.tesfalul@gmail.com" <martha.tesfalul@gmail.com>

Can you and your networks weigh in without breaking the scales?
http://www.economist.com/debate/overview/165

-- 
Youth Alliance for Leadership and Development in Africa
University Hall, First Floor
Box 316
Cambridge, Massachusetts 02138
USA
Website: [www.yaldafrica.org](http://www.yaldafrica.org)
Facebook: YALDA International
Skype: yaldafrica
`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is up to every client, sorry to answer my own question. I noticed Zimbra formats it this way:

```
<blockquote class="gmail_quote" style="margin: 0pt 0pt 0pt 0.8ex; border-left: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); padding-left: 1ex;">
```